# Completion of a ring and the canonical map

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra

Given a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$.

Questions: Can the $R$ be isomorphic to the $I$-adic complection $\hat{R}$ of $R$ without the canonical map $R \rightarrow \hat{R}$ being an isomorphism?
Can this happen when $R$ is noetherian? Can this happend when $I \subseteq rad(R)$?